# How to get something from running Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, testing

I am trying to write some test of my application. I have small parking service and want to do integration test for car entry to the parking and check if any race condition is possible. I checked it by jmeter and app is ok, everything works, race condition is absent but I have to write "classic" test for this. I prepared something like this:

```
@Test
@Sql(scripts = {"/parking-data.sql", "/cars-data.sql"})
void testForRaceConditionWhen2CarsWantToParkAtTheSameTime() throws Exception {
    //given
    CarAtParkingGateRequest carAtGateRequestMode = new CarAtParkingGateRequest("000000000000000000000000000000000001",
            "000000000000000000000000000000000003");

    //when
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        Thread x = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                MvcResult result = mvc.perform(post("/parking/exit")
                                .contentType("application/json")
                                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(carAtGateRequestMode)))
                        .andDo(print())
                        .andReturn();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        x.start();
    }

    //then
}
```

It is of course passes but, how can I for example get response status from every thread.
I was thinking about `List<Integer> expectedStatus = List.of(200,400,400...)` and in other list put that statuses from every thread and next comapre them.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the `result`s? Have you considered submitting [`Callable<MvcResult>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) tasks to a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), and then awaiting the [`Future<MvcResult>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) objects that are returned?

Answer (score 1):

You can approach with `CompletableFuture` like:

```java
{

    CompletableFuture<MvcResult>[] results = new CompletableFuture[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        results[i] = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                mvc.perform(post("/parking/exit")
                                    .contentType("application/json")
                                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(carAtGateRequestMode)))
                            .andDo(print())
                            .andReturn()
        );
    }
    CompletableFuture.allOf(results);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        MvcResult result = results[i].get();
        // test
    }
}
```